# При попытке сохранить файл с кодом сайта создаётся пустой файл

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытался сохранить код страницы, но сохраняется лишь пустой файл, и при попытке его открыть в браузере открывается пустой сайт, при попытке просто вывести код всё работает.Код ошибки ниже:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Костьян\Desktop\Projects\parsing\TEST PARSING.py", line 14, in <module>
    file.write(src)
  File "D:\Projects. Pycharm\Python\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20bd' in position 258343: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для решения нужно явно указать кодировку файла записи.

```
with open("index.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(src)
```